# Spark standalone mode : failed on connection exception:

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark(1.2.1) standalone cluster on my virtual machine(Ubuntu 12.04). I can run the example such as als.py and pi.py successfully. But I can't run the workcount.py example because a connection error will occur.

```
     bin/spark-submit --master spark://192.168.1.211:7077 /examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py ~/Documents/Spark_Examples/wordcount.py
```

The error message is as below:

```
    15/03/13 22:26:02 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager a12:45594 with 267.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, a12, 45594)
    15/03/13 22:26:03 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: a11/192.168.1.211:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
    ......
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/spark/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py", line 32, in <module>
    .reduceByKey(add)
    File "/home/spark/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1 hadoop1.0.4.jar/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1349, in reduceByKey
    File "/home/spark/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1559, in combineByKey
    File "/home/spark/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1942, in _defaultReducePartitions
    File "/home/spark/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar/pyspark/rdd.py", line 297, in getNumPartitions
    ......
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.partitions.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call to a11/192.168.1.211:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ......
```

I didn't use Yarn or ZooKeeper. And all the virtual machines can connect to each other via ssh without password. I also set the SPARK_LOCAL_IP for master and workers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that wordcount.py example is accessing hdfs to reading lines in a file (and then count the words) 
Something like:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://<master-hostname>:9000/path/to/whatever")
```

Port 9000 is usually used for hdfs. 
Please be sure that this file is accessible or do not use hdfs for that example :).
I hope it helps.